# MySQL applys global variables to opened session

Tags: mysql, database, global-variables, session-variables, mysql-variables

I've found that session variables have priority over global variables.

Is it possible to apply global variables which is set by "set global" query to opened session so make local one to same with global one?

Or, is there any way to wait all opened session finish their tasks, and make sleeping session to reconnect?

Answer (score 0):

You can reset any session variable back to its global variable equivalent whenever you want, you don't have to reconnect.

e.g.

```
mysql> SET @@session.foreign_key_checks=0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @@global.foreign_key_checks,@@session.foreign_key_checks;
+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
| @@global.foreign_key_checks | @@session.foreign_key_checks |
+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
|                           1 |                            0 |
+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @@session.foreign_key_checks=@@global.foreign_key_checks;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @@global.foreign_key_checks,@@session.foreign_key_checks;
+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
| @@global.foreign_key_checks | @@session.foreign_key_checks |
+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
|                           1 |                            1 |
+-----------------------------+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: is it valid on only current session?, other opened session will still have @@session.foreign_key_checks with value 0

Comment: That's right, session variables only apply to the connection they are set within.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **session variables** are prioritized to use over **global variables**, and there are **2 kinds of global and session variables**.

- Like **"transaction_isolation"**, one can automatically set **global variables** to **session variables** after changing **global variables** and reconnecting (logging out and logging in) **MySQL**.
- Like **"wait_timeout"**, one cannot automatically set **global variables** to **session variables** after changing **global variables** and reconnecting (logging out and logging in) **MySQL**.

For example about **"transaction_isolation"**, `REPEATABLE-READ` is the default value for **"transaction_isolation" global and session variables** as shown below:

```sql
mysql> SELECT @@global.transaction_isolation, @@session.transaction_isolation;
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+
| @@global.transaction_isolation | @@session.transaction_isolation |
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+
| REPEATABLE-READ                | REPEATABLE-READ                 |
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

Then, we set `READ-UNCOMMITTED` to **"transaction_isolation" global variable** as shown below:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL transaction_isolation = 'READ-UNCOMMITTED';
```

Then, `READ-UNCOMMITTED` is only set to **"transaction_isolation" global variable** as shown below:

```
mysql> SELECT @@global.transaction_isolation, @@session.transaction_isolation;
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+
| @@global.transaction_isolation | @@session.transaction_isolation |
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+
| READ-UNCOMMITTED               | REPEATABLE-READ                 |
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

Then, log out **MySQL**:

```
mysql> exit
```

Then, log in **MySQL**:

```
C:\Users\kai>mysql -u root -p
```

Now, `READ-UNCOMMITTED` is also set to **"transaction_isolation" session variable** as shown below:

```
mysql> SELECT @@global.transaction_isolation, @@session.transaction_isolation;
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+
| @@global.transaction_isolation | @@session.transaction_isolation |
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+
| READ-UNCOMMITTED               | READ-UNCOMMITTED                |
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

And for example about **"wait_timeout"**, `28800` is the default value for **"wait_timeout" global and session variables** as shown below:

```
mysql> SELECT @@global.wait_timeout, @@session.wait_timeout;
+-----------------------+------------------------+
| @@global.wait_timeout | @@session.wait_timeout |
+-----------------------+------------------------+
|                 28800 |                  28800 |
+-----------------------+------------------------+
```

Then, we set `1000` to **"wait_timeout" global variable** as shown below:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL wait_timeout = 1000;
```

Then, `1000` is only set to **"wait_timeout" global variable** as shown below:

```
mysql> SELECT @@global.wait_timeout , @@session.wait_timeout;
+-----------------------+------------------------+
| @@global.wait_timeout | @@session.wait_timeout |
+-----------------------+------------------------+
|                  1000 |                  28800 |
+-----------------------+------------------------+
```

Then, log out **MySQL**:

```
mysql> exit
```

Then, log in **MySQL**:

```
C:\Users\kai>mysql -u root -p
```

Now, `1000` is not set to **"wait_timeout " session variable** as shown below:

```
mysql> SELECT @@global.wait_timeout , @@session.wait_timeout;
+-----------------------+------------------------+
| @@global.wait_timeout | @@session.wait_timeout |
+-----------------------+------------------------+
|                  1000 |                  28800 |
+-----------------------+------------------------+
```

So in this case, just set `1000` to **"wait_timeout " session variable** as shown below;

```
mysql> SET SESSION wait_timeout = 1000;
```

Or, set `DEFAULT` which is **`1000` of "wait_timeout" global variable** to **"wait_timeout" session variable** as shown below:

```
mysql> SET SESSION wait_timeout = DEFAULT;
```

Now, `1000` is also set to **"wait_timeout" session variable** as shown below:

```
mysql> SELECT @@global.wait_timeout, @@session.wait_timeout;
+-----------------------+------------------------+
| @@global.wait_timeout | @@session.wait_timeout |
+-----------------------+------------------------+
|                  1000 |                   1000 |
+-----------------------+------------------------+
```